# Display Google Sheets in mobile mode in desktop browser

Tags: google-sheets

When viewing a Google Sheets in a mobile browser you have handy [filter buttons](http://googledocs.blogspot.se/2009/02/add-edit-sort-and-filter-improved.html) at the top.

How do I display the mobile version of the page in a desktop (preferably Firefox) browser?

I seek to display only Google Sheets that way while displaying non-mobile versions of other websites at the same time. So changing the UA globally won't work.

I found a solution through some URL tweaking: changing the document link URL from `docs.google.com/spreadsheet/ccc?key=...` to `docs.google.com/spreadsheet/lv?key=...` displays the spreadsheet with the desired filter buttons. The "list view" mode can also be toggled from the view menu in spreadsheets when logged in.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Visit a site like http://whatsmyua.com using your mobile browser and note your User Agent string.
2. Use a FF add-on such as [User Agent Switcher](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/user-agent-switcher/) to modify your UA to exactly match that of your mobile browser.
3. Try opening the page and see if you get the mobile version.

Comment: User Agent Switcher's "Iphone 3" displays the spreadsheet as wanted in Firefox. But: it changes UA browser wide. In my use case I need mobile view for spreadsheets and non-mobile view for other sites (re)loaded in other tabs in paralel. I clarified that in the question now.

Answer (score 0):

Try add-on https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/rollapp-file-opener/. It should help you to open file and even modify it.